Nest height from the ground or above the ground? Which one is correct?
Nest height from the ground or above the ground? Which one is correct?
Thanks in advance.

How do I ask a good question?

Both correct. Either okay.

In formal use, I would only use 'height above', or 'height' alone if the ground or sea level is the base being referred to, e.g. he fell from a height of 10 metres and was lucky to escape with a broken leg. Almost always, 'height' alone can be used. If I drop my phone from a height of one metre, I am clearly talking about the floor of the room I am in.

Since some nests are relatively flat and saucer-like while others are deep and bowl-like, "height" alone could be ambiguous.  Put on your ornithologist's hat, Michael :-)

Height from is okay, but height above is better.

@TimR - that hat is made of twigs and has a pair of yellowhammers plus eggs. Wearing it is a lively experience, not least because it drives the cat crazy.

"Height from" expresses the distance from a given point that acts as a reference, in this case the ground immediately below the nest. "Height above" indicates vertical distance. I can't see any difference between the two measurements. (Measuring height is surprisingly complex when you have to take into account things like sea level, uneven ground, etc, but in a context like this, it's quite simple to get a rough distance.) (I'm surprised nobody has objected that "height above" is tautologous, but you definitely need a preposition and "above" is as good as any.)

Thank you all for your answers.

Bird's nest height - different meanings for different birds
I shall begin with a mathematical problem :

A bird's nest is 12 ft above the ground. a moles den is 12 inches below the ground. What is the difference in height of these two positions?

Now coming to the OP question :

Nest height from the ground or above the ground? Which one is correct?


It is necessary to specify what 'from ground' means (above or below). Because there are also birds which burrow. Some birds, like Bank Swallows and Belted Kingfishers, usually construct their own burrows, while others, such as Burrowing Owls, may use the burrows constructed by other species.

Normally we use 'from' when we speak about horizontal distance A to B
Distance from London to Scotland is 740 km.

For birds of the bush like - White-browed Scrubwren, Red-browed Finch, White-winged Chough, Spotted Pardalote, Diamond Firetail, Scarlet Robin, Grey Shrikethrush, Brown Treecreeper, Golden Whistler, Dusky Woodswallow, White-plumed Honeyeater, Fantailed Cuckoo.

For these birds both the terms height from the ground and height off the ground mean the height of the nest above the ground.
For most of the birds we can simply say - The height of the nest - which also is understood as the height of the nest above the ground.

A bald eagles nest may exceed eight feet wide, 12 feet high and weigh more than two tons.
In this case nest height means the depth of the nest. (picture)



The diameter and depth (of height) are the most common metrics used to describe the size of a Bald Eagle Nest. The “Bole” is the central circle where the eggs are laid. The Bole is lined with grass, moss, and other soft nesting material.
(Ref. : https://avianreport.com/bald-eagle-nest/)


Thank you so much @James Mathai for your great answer.
